# Use regex or something else to capture website data

Tags: python, html, regex, web-scraping

I'm trying to use python and regex to pull the price in the example website below but am not getting any results.

How can I best capture the price (I don't care about the cents, just the dollar amount)?

http://www.walmart.com/store/2516/search?dept=4044&dept_name=Home&query=43888060

Relevant HTML:

```
<div class="price-display csTile-price">
       <span class="sup">$</span>
       299
       <span class="currency-delimiter">.</span>
       <span class="sup">00</span>
</div>
```

What would the regex be to capture the "299" or is the an easier route to get this? Thanks!

Comment: Could you show what have you tried and what results have you got?

Comment: most people use a parser like the popular [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/#Download). You can find plenty tutorials online or questions on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=beautiful+soup+findall).

Answer (score 0):

With regexp it can be a bit tricky on how accurate your pattern should be.
I quickly typed something togehter here: https://regex101.com/r/lF5vF2/1

You should get the idea and modify this one to fit your actual needs.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Don't use regex use a html parser like [bs4](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
h = """<div class="price-display csTile-price">
       <span class="sup">$</span>
       299
       <span class="currency-delimiter">.</span>
       <span class="sup">00</span>
</div>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(h)

amount = soup.select_one("div.price-display.csTile-price span.sup").next_sibling.strip()
```

Which will give you:

```
299
```

Or use the `currency-delimiter` span and get the previous element:

```
amount = soup.select_one("span.currency-delimiter").previous.strip()
```

Which will give you the same. The html in your question is also *dynamically generated* via *Javascript* so you won't be getting it using `urllib.urlopen`, it is simply not in the source returned.

You will need something like *selenium* or to mimic the ajax call as below using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) .

```
import requests
import json
js = requests.post("http://www.walmart.com/store/ajax/search",
                    data={"searchQuery":"store=2516&size=18&dept=4044&query=43888060"} ).json()

data = json.loads(js['searchResults'])

from pprint import pprint as pp
pp(data)
```

That gives you some json:

```
{u'algo': u'polaris',
 u'blacklist': False,
 u'cluster': {u'apiserver': {u'hostname': u'dfw-iss-api8.stg0',
                             u'pluginVersion': u'2.3.0'},
              u'searchengine': {u'hostname': u'dfw-iss-esd.stg0.mobile.walmart.com'}},
 u'count': 1,
 u'offset': 0,
 u'performance': {u'enrichment': {u'inventory': 70}},
 u'query': {u'actualQuery': u'43888060',
            u'originalQuery': u'43888060',
            u'suggestedQueries': []},
 u'queryTime': 181,
 u'results': [{u'department': {u'name': u'Home', u'storeDeptId': -1},
               u'images': {u'largeUrl': u'http://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/7b8fd3b1-8eed-4b68-971b-81188ddb238c_1.a181800cade4db9d42659e72fa31469e.jpeg?odnHeight=180&odnWidth=180',
                           u'thumbnailUrl': u'http://i5.walmartimages.com/asr/7b8fd3b1-8eed-4b68-971b-81188ddb238c_1.a181800cade4db9d42659e72fa31469e.jpeg?odnHeight=180&odnWidth=180'},
               u'inventory': {u'isRealTime': True,
                              u'quantity': 1,
                              u'status': u'In Stock'},
               u'isWWWItem': True,
               u'location': {u'aisle': [], u'detailed': []},
               u'name': u'Dyson Ball Multi-Floor Bagless Upright Vacuum, 206900-01',
               u'price': {u'currencyUnit': u'USD',
                          u'isRealTime': True,
                          u'priceInCents': 29900},
               u'productId': {u'WWWItemId': u'43888060',
                              u'productId': u'2FY1C7B7RMM4',
                              u'upc': u'88560900430'},
               u'ratings': {u'rating': u'4.721',
                            u'ratingUrl': u'http://i2.walmartimages.com/i/CustRating/4_7.gif'},
               u'reviews': {u'reviewCount': u'1436'},
               u'score': u'0.507073'}],
 u'totalCount': 1}
```

That gives you dict with all the info you could need, all you are doing is posting the params  and the store  number which you have in the url to `http://www.walmart.com/store/ajax/search`.

To get the price and name:

```
In [22]: import requests

In [23]: import json

In [24]: js = requests.post("http://www.walmart.com/store/ajax/search",
   ....:                     data={"searchQuery":"store=2516&size=18&dept=4044&query=43888060"} ).json()

In [25]: data = json.loads(js['searchResults'])

In [26]: res = data["results"][0]

In [27]: print(res["name"])
Dyson Ball Multi-Floor Bagless Upright Vacuum, 206900-01

In [28]: print(res["price"])
{u'priceInCents': 29900, u'isRealTime': True, u'currencyUnit': u'USD'}
In [29]: print(res["price"]["priceInCents"])
29900

In [30]: print(res["price"]["priceInCents"]) / 100
299
```

Comment: Wow - You're quick!! It'll take me some time to digest. At the moment I have this, which isn't grabbing the price still. Seems like I should tinker with bs4...

Comment: @MiaElla,  urllopen won't give you the source you need, right click in your browse and choose view source, you won't seethe html in your question anywhere. It is loaded via javascript. You need to either  use something like selenium that can handle javascript or so what I have done using requests. I would use the requests logic

Comment: I replicated your json output but got lost in how to implement the portion past "To get the price and name:".

My other goal is to iterate through a list of store #s and output results by store #. Any ideas there? I'm clearly still learning, so apologies on my slow uptake.

Comment: `price  = res["price"]["priceInCents"/ 100` use `/ 100.0` if using python2 and you want the cents also, `name = res["name"])`, obviously following `data = json.loads(js['searchResults'])` and `res = data["results"][0]`, basically just follow the steps in the answer.

Comment: There was a type, `name = res["name"]`

Comment: Got it now - Thanks!!  I'll try and tinker with automating iterating through stores  -- unless that isn't doable this route. Either way, thanks for taking the time to teach me some good pointers.

Comment: No worries, it should work for that site no problem.

Comment: OK - Going to restart this pet project using selenium to hopefully 'age' the page and then parse out accordingly.

Comment: @MiaElla, you don't need Selenium, how is the json not working?

Comment: You're right - I made a mistake in the modified script and was thinking using selenium would be a different route. I'm back to the original json but can't figure out how to import store # via csv to iterate thorugh still. Any ideas there?

Comment: Is this getting me closer to iterating through the csv file?

import requests
import json
import csv
import sys

js = requests.post("http://www.walmart.com/store/ajax/search",
                    data={"searchQuery":"store={Numbers.csv}&size=18&dept=4044&query=43888060"} ).json()


f = open('Numbers.csv', 'rb') # opens the csv file
try:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print row
data = json.loads(js['searchResults'])
res = data["results"][0]

print(res["price"]["priceInCents"]) / 100
finally:
    f.close()      # closing

Answer (score -1):

Ok, just search for numerics (I added $ and .) and concat the results into a string (I used "".join()).

```
>>> txt = """
      <div class="price-display csTile-price">
          <span class="sup">$</span>
            299
          <span class="currency-delimiter">.</span>
          <span class="sup">00</span>
      </div>
      """


>>> ''.join(re.findall('[0-9$.]',txt.replace("\n","")))
'$299.00'
```